# Add data to MYSQL Using HTML FORM and PHP Using method POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm Not so good about PHP, I m still learning that language, so I have made Form which one will add data to mysql using PHP and Method POST. But in when i click on submit nothings happens in the database, no data added.
This is config.php

```
$SETTINGS["hostname"]='localhost';
$SETTINGS["mysql_user"]='username';
$SETTINGS["mysql_pass"]='passw';
$SETTINGS["mysql_database"]='database';
$SETTINGS["data_table"]='defaulttable'; // this is the default database name that we used


/* Connect to MySQL */

if (!isset($install) or $install != '1') {
    $connection = mysql_connect($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"]) or die ('Unable to connect to MySQL server.<br ><br >Please make sure your MySQL login details are correct.');
    $db = mysql_select_db($SETTINGS["mysql_database"], $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');
};
?>
```

and here is my HTML FORM

```
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
      <li>Place Name: <input type="text" name="plname" /></li>
      <li>City: <input type="text" name="plcity" /></li>
      <li>Address: <input type="text" name="pladdress" /></li>
      <li>Terminal QTY: <input type="number" name="plqty" /></li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="save" value="Add Place" /></li>
```

And What About insert.php

```
    <?php
include ("config.php");
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$UserID = $current_user->user_login ;
// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

//$sql="INSERT INTO wp_telemetry_place (plUserID, plName, plCity, plAddress, plTerminalQ) VALUES ('".$UserID."','".$_POST['plname']."','".$_POST['plcity']."','".$_POST['pladdress']."','".$_POST['plqty']."')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_telemetry_place (plUserID, plName, plCity, plAddress, plTerminalQ) VALUES ('{$UserID}','{$_POST['plname']}','{$_POST['plcity']}','{$_POST['pladdress']}','{$_POST['plqty']}')";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

And when I klick to Button for add data, it does not works. No Errors, No Data updated or added in mysql database. What about Passwords, Host, Usernames, Table names etc... I Checked twice :( I would appreciate any helps from your side guys, Thanks in advance and SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Comment: Parameters from the $_POST need to be quoted. $_POST[‘varname’]

Comment: Thank you Roger, I will change it but this does not help :( And What about INJECTIONS I know I'm not doing well but this will not solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah. Didn’t want to go there. Since your beginner. This is not the way to do this professionally. You should lookup MVC and choose a framework. I did t check your code to see what’s the issue. Reading this in my phone :-/ hence my comment .

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is not formatted properly. Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_telemetry_place (plUserID, plName, plCity, plAddress, plTerminalQ) VALUES ('{$UserID}','{$_POST['plname']}','{$_POST['plcity']}','{$_POST['pladdress']}','{$_POST['plqty']}')";
```

Your query is probably giving you an error message, but you have a typo in your code, replace `$conn` with `$connection` to read it, like so:

```
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
```

Finally, and this is important, the way you're writing your code is *hugely* dangerous, because you're accepting user input without any filtering. I recommend you google `SQL injection` to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still not getting any error even if I change $Conn to $connection. and $sql format too. :( and No data in mysql

Comment: [link](https://itcybertech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/db.png) Here is my pick about DB

Comment: After the `$sql = ...` like, write `echo $sql;exit;`, take the SQL query and run it in phpMyAdmin, see if it works. Does it contain the values you wanted?

Comment: Yes it works 1 row inserted. 
Inserted row id: 14 (Query took 0.0001 seconds.)

Comment: NOW I got this error Error: INSERT INTO wp_telemetry_place (plUserID, plName, plCity, plAddress, plTerminalQ) VALUES ('GEeUoMlNou','Macgregor','Gardabaan','Bulvachauri Str 2-11','4')

Answer (score 0):

The main Problem was 'i' I changed

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);}
```

to

```
if (mysql_query($connection, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error($connection);}
```

Now it works perfect, Just I need to look at SQL Injection thats all. Thank you guys anyway :))